# Python3 - MeCabで日本語をエンコードする方法

Tags: python, mecab

環境：Python 3.5.2, MacOS Sierra

エクセルのデータを読み込んで文字列を作り、ReCabを使って名詞と出現回数を出すコードが以下にあります。

```
import pandas as pd
import MeCab
import sys

df = pd.read_excel("filename.xls", sheetname=0)
df = df.dropna()

m = MeCab.Tagger()

noun_list = []
for i in df:
    for l in m.parse (i).splitlines():
        if l != 'EOS' and l.split('\t')[1].split(',')[0] == '名詞':
            noun_list.append(l.split('\t')[0])

noun_cnt = collections.Counter(noun_list)

noun = pd.DataFrame(list(noun_cnt.items()), columns=['名詞', '出現回数'])
noun = noun.sort_values('出現回数', axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')
noun = noun[noun['出現回数'] > 10] # 10回以上出現したもののみ

print(noun.tail())
```

[Out]

```
       word  出現回数
51       心配    18
199      そう    23
171  セキュリティ    31
156      不安    40
154      便利    81
```

手持ちのファイルではコードは走ったのですが、違った日本語データを使いコードを走らせてみると、以下のエラーが出てくるためエンコードの問題であると考えています。

`NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'Tagger_parse'.`

`utf-8`へのencodeとdecodeをコードに入れる必要があると思うのですが、どなたか教えて頂けませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

この問題はPandasとはあまり関係なく、正しく動作する場合と動作しない場合とでMecabの `m.parse(i)` に渡している `i` の形式が異なるために起きているように見えます。文字コードの可能性もありますが、違うかもしれません。

`i` が何物であるかを明確にするために、前の行に `print(i)` や `print(repr(i))` や `print(type(i))` を仕込むなどして、どのようなデータを渡そうとしているのか、確認してみてください。確認ができたら、Pandasを使わない状況で同じ問題を発生させられるか、切り分けてみて下さい。

推測ですが、うまく動作しないときは `i` が文字列ではなく配列や他のデータ形式になっているのではないかと思います。

Comment: エラーは`for l in m.parse (i).splitlines():`からだったのですが、ご指摘通り`print(type(i))`を前の行で試してみたら、新しいデータには`str`だけでなく`int`も含まれていたので、`i = str(i)`を入れることで問題が解決できました。ありがとうございました。